# Node.js using child.spawn multiple times

Tags: javascript, java, node.js, child-process

In my node.js application I'm using child.spawn multiple times for multiple files, each file is a java file (.jar).
Each file is spawning its own java.exe process which is around 65MB of memory (RAM).
After few minutes the memory used is dropping to 10M and less which is a huge difference.
I wonder, why the process is consuming x6 more RAM for the first 10-15minutes.
Also, is there any possible way to reduce the overall amount of memory being used?
I have seen some suggestions of using a worker that execute a script.js file and than the script.js will be responsible of spawning the childs.